# useEffect is called multiple times

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am fetching a list of series from the MySQL db using Express API. I checked on Express logs and see the request is made 2 times. I console logged the react component and the useEffect hook and see the component itself is rendered 5-6 times and the useEffect his rendered 2 times (based on the console log outputs in the chrome browser). What am i doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { fetchSeries } from '../../Redux/Actions/SeriesActions';

const MyList = () => {
  const [isSeriesOpen, setIsSeriesOpen] = useState(false);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const series = useSelector((state) => state.seriesList.series);
  const userId = useSelector((state) => state.auth.user_id);
  const companyId = 3;

  console.log("Log from the component");

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchSeries(userId, companyId));
    console.log("Log for Effect called");
  }, [dispatch]);


  return (
    <div>
      <p> Test Content</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyList;
```

I tried checking if there is anything making the component re-render. The component is imported in the Routes which is imported in the App.js which is imported in index.js. But this is a normal structure for React, isnt it? I dont undertsnad why useEffect is called 2 times and hence 2 requests are made to the api causeing it to run query on the db 2 times.

Comment: In development (if you use strict mode and >=v18) every component will be mounted, unmounted, and mounted again on the first render to check for improper usage of hooks amongst other things. It's a bit surprising and annoying, but it's also covered in their documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React renders twice while in development.

See:

> "    Strict mode can't automatically detect side effects for you, but
> it can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic.
> This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:
> Class component constructor , render , and shouldComponentUpdate
> methods."

Source: [React Docs: Strict Mode](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects)

Also, you should add all the variables that are used inside the useEffect, into the dependency array at the end

```
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchSeries(userId, companyId));
    console.log("Log for Effect called");
  }, [dispatch, userId, companyId]);
```

Comment: My understanding is that useEffect will everytime the dispatch is called and hence I gave the dependency of dispatch alone. the userId and companyId are never gping to be changed. Do i still need to include them in the dependency array?